# List cant store the input append attribute error

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know why I'm getting this error. The list has a function called append which adds the data to the list. But my code gives an error: `int object has no attribute append`. My codes input was

```
1 
5
.....
.*...
.....
.....
```

I cant able to store the input in nested lists.Its shows an runtime error.Help me solve this.

```
    t=int(input())
    l=[]
    for i in range(t):
        n=int(input())
        for x in range(n):
            l.appen(list(input()))
```

I expected that the input will be stored as a nested list,but it throws an error int object has no attribute append.

Comment: I didn't get any error running this code... (after changing `appen`, to `append`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing in Python's IDLE, this is a common mistake that happens with me. '1' looks almost same as 'l', so make sure.

```
t=int(input())
l=[]
for i in range(t):
    n=int(input())
    for x in range(n):
        l.append(list(input()))  # 'appen' is not a list attribute, 'append' is.
```

You can comment on this answer for more queries on this topic. I'll be eager to answer  them

I hope it helped.

Comment: Oh really! Let me try.

Comment: Yes it is ! What an amazing piece of info.

Comment: Yeah. I should be ashamed of myself. :(

Comment: Actually I have used input with strings, never done without it.